# Taking the average of values from a range of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column called 'coverage'. For a series of specific index values, I'd like to get the mean 'coverage' value for the 100 prior rows. For example, for index position 1001, I want the mean 'coverage' for rows 901-1000. My index values of interest are in a separate list.

I'm stumped on how to tell pandas to look at a series of rows relative to a given index. I don't think I can use GroupBy, since there will be some groups of rows that overlap (for example, suppose my list of index values of interest includes 1001 and 1050).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: it sounds like all you want to do is iterate over the list and then slice your main df using the list range values?

Comment: Yes EdChum, that sounds like what I want to do. Guillaume's answer below gave me a good tool for finding the means. Right now I'm adding a new column that marks rows with indexes I'm interested in, then conditionally applying the rolling_mean function. My method for how I use the index list to access the mean df is clunky, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

[pandas.rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) seems like a good candidate for your problem

For instance:

```
In [9]: pandas.rolling_mean(pandas.Series(range(10)), window=2)
Out[9]: 
0    NaN
1    0.5
2    1.5
3    2.5
4    3.5
5    4.5
6    5.5
7    6.5
8    7.5
9    8.5
dtype: float64
```